# Вывод ячеек таблицы с интервалом в 5 секунд

Tags: javascript, html, матрицы

Здравствуйте! Есть двумерная матрица. Мне надо распарсить ее в табличку, но так, чтобы каждая ячейка таблицы появлялась с интервалом в 5 секунд.

Вот, что есть на данный момент:

```
document.write('<table>');        
for(c = 0; c<dimension; c++){
  document.write('<tr>');
    for(r = 0; r<dimension; r++){
      document.write('<td>'+ matrix[c][r] + '</td>');
    }         
  document.write('</tr>');
}
document.write('</table>');
```

здесь я вывожу каждый элемент матрицы в отдельную ячейку. Получается вот такая табличка: 
[image: изображение таблички]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать так, чтобы каждая ячейка таблички появлялась с задержкой?

Comment: вставлялась в документ с задержкой или именно появлялась?

Comment: @MedvedevDev вставлялась в документ с задержкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Добавляем таблицу, в которой все ячейки будут пустые
- Пишем функцию, которая будет заполнять следующую ячейку
- Делаем, чтобы эта функция вызывалась каждые x секунд (с помощью [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)).
- Когда таблица заполнится нужно вызывать метод [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).
- Изменить содержимое ячейки таблицы можно так: `table.rows[индекс_строки].cells[индекс_столбца].innerHTML = новое_значение`

```js
let size = 5;
let matrix = [];
for (let i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  matrix[i] = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
    matrix[i][j] = i + j;
  }
}

document.write('<table>');
for (c = 0; c < size; c++) {
  document.write('<tr>');
  for (r = 0; r < size; r++) {
    document.write('<td></td>');
  }
  document.write('</tr>');
}
document.write('</table>');

let table = document.querySelector('table');
let i = 0;
let j = 0;

function addNewCell() {
  table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = matrix[i][j];
  ++j;
  if (j === size) {
    j = 0;
    ++i;
  }
  if (i === size) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}

let intervalId = setInterval(addNewCell, 100);
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за Вашу помощь) Но у меня немного другая ситуация. Помните, мы вчера с вами делали заполнение матрицы по спирали? Так вот мне надо, чтобы именно по спирали они и в документе появлялись. Вот я не понимаю как мне это сделать(

Comment: Откуда все эти задачи про матрицы?) Как сделать по спирали сейчас напишу.

Comment: Олимпиадные задачи по JS) Мне преподаватель дал в универе. Надо разобраться)

Comment: Понятно. Предлагаю заранее создать массив индексов, в том порядке, в котором должны заполняться соответствующие ячейки. Индекс можно представить в виде массива длина два. Изначально массив пустой, в каждой итерации цикла, который заполнял матрицу по спирали, будем добавлять в этот массив новый элемент. Далее, вместо переменных i и j, которые в моём коде отвечали за текущую ячейку, заведём одну переменную, индекс в массиве индексов. При каждом вызове метода addNewCell будем увеличивать эту переменную, когда она достигнет size*size вызовем clearInterval.

Comment: @diraria, у меня скорее вопрос откуда у вас такие познания по двумерным массивам?) Уже второй раз смотрю ваши логику/разъяснения/решения и диву даюсь, как вы так быстро это делаете, что я не успею свой вариант написать, который основан лишь на внутренних ощущениях, а не на последовательной логике )

Comment: @diraria Немного не поняла как это,  создать массив индексов, в том порядке, в котором должны заполняться соответствующие ячейки.

Comment: @diraria Как же мне предугадать массив индексов, если у меня размерность матрицы может быть любая?

Comment: @diraria Это получается надо весь предыдущий код переписывать?

Comment: @kittycat_13, нет, не надо, конечно. Давай в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65035/discussion-between-kittycat-13-and-diraria), там удобней

Comment: @MedvedevDev, решал олимпиадные задачки. Вы тоже можете порешать, например на сайте http://codeforces.ru/. Они очень хорошо развивают. Если захотите порешать, могу подсказать как там что работает.

Comment: @diraria, благодарю. Просто за последние пару дней задачи по матрицам на SO - самые интересные и которые хочется решать невзирая на затраченное время, но чувствуется, что решаю скорее по наитию.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, вот на CodeForces очень много задач, и на матрицы и на всё остальное, рекомендую попробовать порешать там, может понравится.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, вот например, [список](http://codeforces.com/problemset/tags/matrices) задач на матрицы). Там только выбирай задачи, которые заканчиваются на букву `A` или `B`.

Comment: @diraria, задачи выглядят пугающе ... вроде в школе любил все эти математические дисциплины, но сейчас я на столько от всех этих формулировок задач далек, но попробую вникнуть ... )

Comment: @MedvedevDev, пугающе, да, просто там много сложных вперемешку с простыми. Справа можно отсортировать по числу решивших, тогда будет лучше. [Вот](http://codeforces.com/problemset/tags/matrices?order=BY_SOLVED_DESC) если что ссылка с уже применённой сортировкой.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, что-то там всё равно сложные. Можно ещё метку [реализация](http://codeforces.com/problemset/tags/implementation?order=BY_SOLVED_DESC) посмотреть, там вроде попроще

Comment: @diraria, да ладно, как сориентироваться придумаю xDD